# 2D to 1D array in c

Tags: arrays, 2d

I am studying genetic algorithms and the C programming language. My task is to read in a matrix which represents a connected graph then calculate a fitness based on the distance between nodes, the prof has made it clear this does not have to be exact, nor necessarily follow the constraints on a graph. SO my idea is to read the matrix in to a 2D array which works. I now need to get that 2D array into a 1D array we will call rack, we then jumble the rack and split it into two smaller array of equal length.

The matrix is 20*20 so rack has to be of size 400.

Anyways this is my code for doing this, although it does not work.

```
void TwoDtoOneD(int array[][SIZE], int left[SIZE*SIZE]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE*SIZE;i++){
        for(j=0;j<SIZE*SIZE;j++){
            left[i] = array[i][j];
        }//end for
    }//end for
}
```

Comment: You need a third variable k to count the index of `left[k++]`, not `left[i]`

Answer (score 0):

`left[j+i*SIZE] = array[i][j]`

Walk the logic of how each entry in left fills with your loops, then worry about putting the array data as you want.

Answer (score 0):

By doing two fors and making them iterate untill SIZE^2, you're making `array[i]` iterate too much.
`i` should only go till 20(or SIZE), wich is the max of the `i` and the `j` for your matrix.
To make this work, you'll need a third variable wich is incremented every time you change a value to your vector(left), and this variable has nothing to do with the for loop variable initiation.

So, for your example, it would be like this:

```
void TwoDtoOneD(int array[SIZE][SIZE], int left[SIZE*SIZE]){  /
  int i,j,k;
  k=0;
  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
     for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++){
        left[k] = array[i][j];
        k++;
     }//end for
  }//end for
}
```

Now, your `left[]` array has `k+1` elements and you can iterate through it till `k`.

Just to finish, since you're working with graphs, try to read some stuff about graph path algorithms ([Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), [Floyd's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), [Johnson's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)...), you'll see that are an infinity of really well thought solutions for all your graph's problems (or for most).

Hope this helps. Good luck!